# How can I remove the space between the lines of linguistic examples?

Tags: linguistics, examples, expex

When a linguistic example is very long, the defined format of such long examples in the `expex` package looks like this. How can I make the first part and second part of this long example align?

```
\ex[everygla=,glhangstyle=normal]<@period>
\begingl
\gla a\textsuperscript{55}mu\textsuperscript{13} \nogloss{[} @ la\textsuperscript{31}lo\textsuperscript{31}pa\textsuperscript{31} z\textepsilon \textsuperscript{31}m\textepsilon \textsuperscript{31} \nogloss{*(} @ ni\textsuperscript{55}kh\textepsilon \textsuperscript{55}) t\textrtails hi\textsuperscript{31}-ma\textsuperscript{55}] bi\textsuperscript{31} u\textsuperscript{33}di\textsuperscript{33} ha\textsuperscript{33} mu\textsuperscript{31}. z\textepsilon \textsuperscript{31}m\textepsilon \textsuperscript{31} na\textsuperscript{55} t\textrtails hi\textsuperscript{31}-ma\textsuperscript{55} t\textrtails ho\textsuperscript{31} m\textepsilon \textsuperscript{31} mu\textsuperscript{55}.//
\glb Amu Yi-ethnicity girl nikhe one-CL marry want SFP VIS girl that one-CL very beautiful VIS//
\glft `Amu wants to marry a girl of Yi ethnicity. That girl is very beautiful.'//
\endgl
\xe
```

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, your code snippet is not enough to describe the problem. Can you please complete it to a minimal document LaTeX can be run on so as to see the issue?

Comment: By aligning the "first part and second part", do you mean you want the example gloss to be *not* indented when it continues on a new line? You didn't include an image of your example, so it's not clear what you're referring to.

Comment: Guessing, because you haven't responded to comments, but if you change to `glhangstyle=none` the subsequent lines won't have a hanging indent.

Comment: thank you so much, it actually worked, I generally followed the default setting.